# APL2, order of processing each operator arguments

Tags: each, operator-keyword, apl

Assuming the user function:

```
∇ f b
[1] b
∇
```

and the following is executed:
`f¨1 2 3`

Three lines will display, 1 digit per line. In APLX the order is 1 2 3.
Is there any APL2 guarantee the order the digits will be displayed?

This can be critical if the user function has side-effects.
I'd think this would be documented somewhere, but heck if I can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APL Language Reference says:

> ```
> ⁝
> Z←0ρV
> L1:→(0=ρV)/L1X
> Z←Z,⊂F↑V
> V←1↓V
> →L1
> L1X:
> ⁝
> ```
>
> The above loop can be replaced by:
>
> ```
> Z←F¨ V
> ```

This clearly implies that `¨` runs in reliable order.

Furthermore, the ISO/IEC 13751 (2001) *Programming language Extended APL*, which is based on APL2, says:

> Create *`Z`*, an array having the same **shape-list** as *`B`*.
>  For each *`I`* in the index-set of the **ravel-list** of *`Z`*:
>   For form **f¨***`B`*,
>    Set *`X`* to item *`I`* of the **ravel-list** of *`B`*.
>    **Evaluate-Monadic-Function** with **f***`X`* giving **token T**.

This clearly specifies that the operand is to be applied in sequence, its evaluation needing completion before proceding to the next item in the ravel order.

Comment: The loop empties V, the "each" form does not, so that's not "replaceable" code.  That documentation states what "each" does, but I still don't see why "each" couldn't execute  F  on the elements of   V   backwards (or simultaneously?) as long as the  Z  result elements are ordered corresponding to the elements of V.  Again my concern is side-effects from  F  that affect how  F  operates in subsquent invokations.  Having said that, you've convinced me I'm looking for trouble where none exists.  I just wish I could find somewhere this aspect is specifically discussed.

Comment: @PaulHoule I've added a quote from the standard that does promise safety in side effects.

Comment: thanks!  I'll always be unsure of the ordering though.  "For each I" means do them all, but that doesn't explicitly say in ascending order (at least to me).  Another page (160) in ISO/IEC 13751 talks about a similar sequencing issue -- that the indexed assignment a[1 1 1]←1 2 3 must leave 3 in a[1].  That pseudocode explicity indicates ascending order by starting with  "set M to one" and between iterations "set M to M plus one".

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the Each's order of evaluation is left unspecified by design. However, Reduce to the rescue? Something like `⊢∘f⍨/⌽0 1 2 3` should get the job done, IIUC. The only quirk is needing to add an (ultimately ignored) initial element, like `0` in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

"This clearly specifies that the operand is to be applied in sequence, its evaluation needing completion before proceding to the next item in the ravel order."

It actually does not. The standard merely says that every item in
the index-set of the ravel-list of Z is being considered, but not
in which order.

Different interpreters may use different orders (normally
either first-to-last or else last-to-first), but the same interpreter
is unlikely to use different orders.

Comment: "It actually does not. The standard merely says that every item in the index-set of the ravel-list of Z is being considered, but not in which order." should be a comment on my post, and your last paragraph should be backed by a source.

Comment: The source is your own quote from the ISO standard. I am not too familiar with stack overflow, so I beg your pardon for incorrectly posting my comment.